# Validation in ASP.MVC 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have a model class :

```
public class YearlyChageRate
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public double Rate { get; set; }
}
```

and I want to check that Yeae is unique or no and in condition Year is not unique application show an error message to users.How can I check the Year filed is repeated or not?

Comment: Where do you want to perform this check? What does it mean that an year is unique? Unique where? In a database or something?

Comment: Yes unique in database , I want to check in server side and show a message to user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good example:
http://tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asp-net-mvc-remote-validation-for-multiple-fields-with-additionalfields-property

And here too: [MVC validation for unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590883/mvc-validation-for-unique)

You can use Remote attribute in your model to perform check for unique value in database.

This is official example of Remote attribute: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(v=vs.98).aspx

And one more: http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?Id=198

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`[Remote]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) validation attribute on your view model.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can use DataAnnotations attributes for validation and the `[Remote]` attribute for checks against the DB, it's not a very good design choice.

Let me explain:

- data access is a data-layer matter
- validation is a business-layer matter
- user input and feedback is a ui matter

With DataAnnotations, you're mixin 3 in 1. It can be faster, but surely not well designed.

You could try a more disciplinate approach, like this:

- Have a method at business level that will take your object as a parameter, perform validation internally using a validation framework of your choiche;
- This method will call the data access to persist the object only if the validation passed;
- This method will always return to the UI the validated object, plus a collection of fields/errors if anything didn't validate;
- When you read the output of the method in your ui, you can either display a success page if there were no errors, or redisplay the form with the validation errors returned. To do this, the use of the `PRG pattern` is highly recommended, as you should never display a page on a `POST` method. Google for the `PRG pattern` to learn more about it. MvcContrib has a nice `ActionFilter` called `ModelStateToTempData` to make the implementation of the PRG pattern something trivial.