# MultiColumn Unique Data Annotation - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, annotations

I have two properties (First Name & Last Name) that I want both to be unique so the Full Name is Unique in database, so I searched here for a solution and found this

[Unique multiple column in EF6 codefirst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26432576/unique-multiple-column-in-ef6-codefirst)

and I applied It

```
    [Required]
    [Index("IX_fullname", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public string f_name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Index("IX_fullname", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public string l_name { get; set; }
```

but it did not work at all.

The link provided of the solution is actually the same solution I provided the link of, and actually it did not work, I can do what I want with JSON and I did that with code but I can't handle it to show the message after leaving the text box immediately like "this value is required".

Comment: You're asking too much in one question. You should have stopped after the first problem that you insufficiently describe by "but it did not work at all". *How* did it not work?

Comment: I just tried to solve it , I did not want my question to be marked as a duplicate, The problem is one after all , Multi-Column Uniqueness in my model.

Comment: Anyway I will do as you said and remove unnecessary additions, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting unique Constraint with fluent API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21573550/setting-unique-constraint-with-fluent-api)

Comment: Or: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7590883/861716

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

[Setting unique Constraint with fluent API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21573550/setting-unique-constraint-with-fluent-api)

It appears you also need to add a StringLength attribute to use this annotation.

Comment: The link provided of the solution is actually the same solution I provided the link of, and actually it did not work, I can do what I want with JSON and I did that with code but I can't handle it to show the message after leaving the text box immediately like "this value is required".